# .I in R data.table: what is the rational for the different behaviors

Tags: r, data.table

I am struggling to understand the behavior of `.I` in `data.table`.
Here is the example

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(x = 1:50)

dt[x>3,.I]
dt[,.I[x>3]]
dt[x>3,.I,by = x]$I
```

I do not understand the rationale for the behavior of the last line (although I find it practical).

`dt[x>3,.I]` gives the lines of the subseted dt. So from 1 to 47.

```
dt[x>3,.I]

[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43
[44] 44 45 46 47
```

`dt[,.I[x>3]]` gives the line where `x>3`, so from 4 to 50:

```
dt[,.I[x>3]]

 [1]  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46
[44] 47 48 49 50
```

But why does the use of a grouping operation on the subsetted dataset still give the line of the entire dt where the subset condition is true ?

```
dt[x>3,.I,by = x]$I
 [1]  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46
[44] 47 48 49 50
```

Comment: From `?.I`, *"`.I` is an integer vector equal to `seq_len(nrow(x))`. While grouping, it holds for each item in the group, its row location in `x`. This is useful to subset in `j`; e.g. `DT[, .I[which.max(somecol)], by=grp]`."*

Comment: So I think `.I` is working exactly as documented. If your question is "why did the authors create `.I` to be this way?", that seems like an opinion-based question that's not really on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: (somewhat) Related reading: [local and global versions of .`I`, `.N`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1206)

Comment: @GregorThomas But the row location in `dt[x>3,.I,by = x]$I` is from `dt[x>3]`, so first group should start at 1 ?

Comment: @denis, you actually answer it in your last question asked here yourself ;) YES first .GRP should start at 1 (and it does), while .I will start at 4 as it is supposed to do. Compare  `dt[x > 3, .I, by = x]` versus `dt[x > 3, .GRP, by = x]`

Comment: @GregorThomas "As you point out .i gives the row number in the whole data, not the subset data" no, because `dt[x>3,.I]` does not give the row in the whole data, but in the subseted one: `dt[x>3,.I]` and `dt[x > 3, ][, .I]` give the same result!

Answer (score 3):

I think I start to understand the confusion.

```
dt[x > 3, .I]
```

Here data.table subsets first and returns a vector with row numbers based on the subset.

```
dt[, .I[x > 3]]
```

Here you do not subset and assign a row number to every row in dt, but return them for x > 3

```
dt[x > 3, .I, by = x]$I
```

Here the tricky one, you think you are subsetting first, but you are not. Note that not a vector is returned, as you create that afterwards adding $I. You see that data.table here assigns by reference the row number to each row only WHERE (i) x > 3 as you group by every row and then subsets. It seems that the by changes the order of subsetting and does actually the same as `dt[, .I, by = x][x > 3]`